Concat variable in Azure DevOps Yml
I want to concat predefined variable with text in counter expression in azure devops yml
Using format seems to work but I wanted to know if I can concat in another way.
Format
- name: BUILD_NUMBER
  value: $[counter(format('{0}_iis', variables['Build.SourceBranch']), 180)]

Concat (doesn't works)
- name: BUILD_NUMBER
  value: $[counter('$(Build.SourceBranch)_iis', 180)]


What exactly does it mean doesn't work? Is there any error? Value is not as expected? using a script task like - script: echo $(BUILD_NUMBER) works for both cases.

@juanDYB, you cannot use marco syntax for variable in expression.  For predefined variable Build.SourceBranch, you can use template expression as it expands at compile time. I added the details below, thanks.

The 2nd yaml doesn't work because you are using macro syntax($(var)) in the counter expression. Since you have _iis combined with the value, you can use template expression for the variable:
variables:
- name: BUILD_NUMBER
  value: $[counter('${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}_iis', 180)]

Or use your 1st expression, format with runtime expression:
- name: BUILD_NUMBER
  value: $[counter(format('{0}_iis', variables['Build.SourceBranch']), 180)]

Please check the doc What syntax should I use? for your reference.

Thanks! With template expression seems to be more simple than using format.

Glad to know it helps! Happy day!
